# CS50 pset4 - filter (less comfortable), sepia function

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote code for the sepia function of the filter pset. The code compiles without any errors but the output image is not entirely sepia. However, after I wrote the code in different way it works fine. Can someone explain why this happens?

First code:

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE pixel={0,0,0};
            RGBTRIPLE pix = image[i][j];

            pixel.rgbtBlue = round(0.272 * pix.rgbtRed + 0.534 * pix.rgbtGreen + 0.131 * pix.rgbtBlue);
            pixel.rgbtGreen = round(0.349 * pix.rgbtRed + 0.686 * pix.rgbtGreen + 0.168 * pix.rgbtBlue);
            pixel.rgbtRed = round(0.393 * pix.rgbtRed + 0.769 * pix.rgbtGreen + 0.189 * pix.rgbtBlue);

            if(pixel.rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                pixel.rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
             if(pixel.rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                pixel.rgbtGreen = 255;
            }

             if(pixel.rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                pixel.rgbtRed = 255;
            }

            image[i][j] = pixel;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

first code output image:

[image: first code output image]

Second Code:

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            int green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            int blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            //calculate sepia values
            int sepiaRed = round(.393 * red + .769 * green + .189 * blue);
            if(sepiaRed > 255)
            {
                sepiaRed = 255;
            }

            int sepiaGreen = round(.349 * red + .686 * green + .168 * blue);
            if(sepiaGreen > 255)
            {
                sepiaGreen = 255;
            }

            int sepiaBlue = round(.272 * red + .534 * green + .131 * blue);
            if(sepiaBlue > 255)
            {
                sepiaBlue = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed  = sepiaRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;


        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Second code output:

[image: second code output image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two versions is that the type in which you compute the new pixel value

In the first version the type is whatever the constituent members of `RGBTRIPLE` are - which I assume is an unsigned 8-bit integer.

```
 pixel.rgbtBlue = round(0.272 * pix.rgbtRed + 0.534 * pix.rgbtGreen + 0.131 * pix.rgbtBlue);
```

In this line (and the equivalents for green and red pixels),
the value can exceeded `255` which then gets truncated by assignment to an 8-bit unsigned int on assignment to `pixel.rgbtBlue`.

The following clamp to saturation:

```
    if(pixel.rgbtBlue > 255)
    {
        pixel.rgbtBlue = 255;
    }
```

Will always excute false, as `pixel.rgbtBlue` cannot hold a value bigger than `255`.

In the second version of the code, an `int` is used, which is larger, and in which truncation does not occur, allowing the clamp-to-255 to work correct.

Comment: You might want to think about enabling compiler warnings: It likely that the truncation would generate one.

Comment: *"I assume is an unsigned 8-bit integer."* I believe this is correct - according to [this](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/a/16679), the structure contains 3x `BYTE`, aka, `uint8_t`.

Comment: Note that [*"truncation"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) is not the correct term. This is [unsigned integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Definition_variations_and_ambiguity), resulting in the value *wrapping*.

Answer (score 0):

As people above already comment, the first one has a truncated value in the if conditions, as the avarage operation is resulting in a number bigger than 255... That's why the filter does not work properly.
I would consider as well less "if/else" on the second one, using perhaps a "[Ternary Operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/)", for a cleaner code:

```
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (sepiaGreen > 255) ? 255 : sepiaGreen;
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = (sepiaRed > 255) ? 255 : sepiaRed;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (sepiaBlue > 255) ? 255 : sepiaBlue;
```